# Real-Time Strategy Gameplay

Tags: game-design

I am working on building a HTML5 RTS game, and my current state is that I am building the Campaign mode of the game, and want to define the gameplay (The Scoring, Unit Behaviors/Attributes).

I am searching for links/articles/books about how to define the gameplay, for me this:

- The scoring
- Figuring out levels of control (in any RTS game, there is units, individuals and squads)
- Unit action/attributes/properties
- point timing (how long it will take to play?)
- Achievements
- ..etc

I want to see how they usually define these areas in RTS games, I expect to see general document discussing this concept that I can use to build the gameplay.

Any idea? Is my question clear or I need to provide more details?

Comment: This question is too broad. Any one of your bullet points could be one or more questions. If you could start with the experience you want in your campaign and then narrow to a specific feature and how they work towards that goal, then we could provide direct answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lot of this depends on what **type** of RTS you want to create.

For example, if it is more casual, just multiply all scores by 100 and make sure that each game session is short :P.

RTS games are very mathematical, the balance needs to be perfect because players will find how to exploit any bad balancing, and while this may not be a bad thing, it can break your game. This is why I think it is imperative to read about this stuff.

There are some interesting articles on RTS design [here](http://www.oxeyegames.com/category/rts-design/).

I would first though, define the game experience. What you want the player to do in general, what the game will be like, etc. Your question seems more about balancing and macro/micro controlling, which are mechanics used to **implement** your game, they **shouldn't** influence your design (but most probably will).

You need to ask if you want to give advantages between races, unit types, etc. then you need to study the mechanics to balance your game out so in any situation you have the rock-paper-scissors effect.